How can i scale a deployment using an YAML file?
I don't understand about kubectl.
I'm trying to scale a pod using Cronjob in Huawei Cloud. I've resolved how to scale then using Linux Terminal and it works, but when i try to use the kubectl, it brings me the following error:
`error:
I have the following YAML code from a kubectl in Huawei Cloud:
kind: CronJob
apiVersion: batch/v1
metadata:
  name: resize-app01-test
  namespace: my-namespace-hmg
  uid: <my-private-uid>
  resourceVersion: '<xxx>'
  generation: 19
  creationTimestamp: '2024-07-30T13:38:49Z'
  annotations:
    description: ''
  managedFields:
    - manager: cfe-apiserver
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2024-07-30T16:41:37Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:metadata:
          f:annotations:
            .: {}
            f:description: {}
        f:spec:
          f:concurrencyPolicy: {}
          f:failedJobsHistoryLimit: {}
          f:jobTemplate:
            f:spec:
              f:template:
                f:metadata:
                  f:labels:
                    .: {}
                    f:app: {}
                    f:version: {}
                f:spec:
                  f:containers:
                    k:{"name":"container-teste"}:
                      .: {}
                      f:args: {}
                      f:command: {}
                      f:env:
                        .: {}
                        k:{"name":"PAAS_APP_NAME"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:value: {}
                        k:{"name":"PAAS_NAMESPACE"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:value: {}
                        k:{"name":"PAAS_PROJECT_ID"}:
                          .: {}
                          f:name: {}
                          f:value: {}
                      f:image: {}
                      f:imagePullPolicy: {}
                      f:name: {}
                      f:resources:
                        .: {}
                        f:limits:
                          .: {}
                          f:cpu: {}
                          f:memory: {}
                        f:requests:
                          .: {}
                          f:cpu: {}
                          f:memory: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePath: {}
                      f:terminationMessagePolicy: {}
                  f:dnsConfig:
                    .: {}
                    f:options: {}
                  f:dnsPolicy: {}
                  f:imagePullSecrets:
                    .: {}
                    k:{"name":"default-secret"}: {}
                  f:restartPolicy: {}
                  f:schedulerName: {}
                  f:securityContext: {}
                  f:terminationGracePeriodSeconds: {}
          f:schedule: {}
          f:successfulJobsHistoryLimit: {}
          f:suspend: {}
          f:timeZone: {}
    - manager: kube-controller-manager
      operation: Update
      apiVersion: batch/v1
      time: '2024-07-30T16:43:38Z'
      fieldsType: FieldsV1
      fieldsV1:
        f:status:
          f:lastScheduleTime: {}
          f:lastSuccessfulTime: {}
      subresource: status
spec:
  schedule: "43 13 * * *"
  timeZone: America/Sao_Paulo
  concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
  suspend: false
  jobTemplate:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          creationTimestamp: null
          labels:
            app: resize-app01-teste
            version: v1
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: container-teste
              image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
              command:
                - /bin/sh
              args:
                - '-c'
                - kubectl scale --replicas=3 deployment/workload-v2-app01-hmg -n app01-hmg
              env:
                - name: PAAS_APP_NAME
                  value: resize-app01-teste
                - name: PAAS_NAMESPACE
                  value: app01-hmg
                - name: PAAS_PROJECT_ID
                  value: <my-project-id>
              resources:
                limits:
                  cpu: 250m
                  memory: 512Mi
                requests:
                  cpu: 250m
                  memory: 512Mi
              terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
              terminationMessagePolicy: File
              imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 60
          dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
          securityContext: {}
          imagePullSecrets:
            - name: default-secret
          schedulerName: default-scheduler
          dnsConfig:
            options:
              - name: single-request-reopen
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
status:
  lastScheduleTime: '2024-07-30T16:43:00Z'
  lastSuccessfulTime: '2024-07-30T13:40:03Z'

when the Cronjob is executed, the console brings me this error:
Error - no objects passed to scale

How can i resolve this?
I've tried to split the command: and args: like that ways:
1° try:
command:
- /bin/sh
- '-c'
- kubectl
- scale --replicas=3 
- deployment/workload-v2-app01-hmg -n app01-hmg

2° try:
command:
- /bin/sh
args:
- '-c'
- kubectl
- scale --replicas=3 
- deployment/workload-v2-app01-hmg -n app01-hmg

3° try:
command:
- /bin/sh
args:
- '-c'
- kubectl scale --replicas=3 deployment/workload-v2-app01-hmg -n app01-hmg


I wouldn't use sh -c here.  I'd do something more like [kubectl, scale, --replicas=3, ...] making sure each word is a separate item in the YAML list (don't try to group words together into the same list item).

This isn't directly an answer, but your 1st and 2nd tries are doomed to failure because of how you've structured them. When you're using sh -c '...some script...', note that the -c option only takes a single argument. That means that when you do this:
command:
- /bin/sh
- '-c'
- kubectl
- scale --replicas=3 
- deployment/workload-v2-app01-hmg -n app01-hmg

Or this:
command:
- /bin/sh
args:
- '-c'
- kubectl
- scale --replicas=3 
- deployment/workload-v2-app01-hmg -n app01-hmg

In both cases the argument to sh -c is kubectl, and nothing else. The remaining arguments become positional parameters to the script passed to -c.
It's critical to understand this, because you're going to run into similar situations many times as you work with kubernetes.
The canonical way of embedding a shell script in a pod/deployment is to do something like this is:
command:
- /bin/sh
- -c
- |
  echo your shell script
  echo goes here

Using the | literal block quote operator allows you to format a shell script as you normally would.

Your third try appears correct, assuming that your code is running under a serviceaccount with appropriate privileges.
